# LaTexIt doesn't render after using the library

Tags: latexit

If I don't use the LaTexIt library everything is fine. However once I display an equation from the library LaTexIt no longer renders. It seems that using the library screws up the scaling as when I drag the scroll bar down in the top window I can see the equation but it is tiny. Also if in Settings -> General I select "Fit preview size to window" the equation is displayed at the top of the display window but it is tiny. I am using Latex 2.16.5 on MacOS 13.4